# Getting Index out of range error while trying to do Totaling statements

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to do a multiple totaling statements but it keeps saying index out of range.
Here is the section of code:

```
for m in range(len(mo)):
  for o in range(len(mag)):
    if mag[o] == 0 and mo[m] ==1 :
        countfujita[m] = countfujita[m] + 1
```

and I am trying to get the totals into list a list such as this:
countfujita = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: You will need to tell us what mag and mo are in order to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @mcsoini couldn't agree more re your previous comment abt communication.

Comment: your issue is likely due to the lenght of `countfujita` not being what you expect it to be. Is this an existing list? Is this a new list? As mentioned by the other 2 above me, we need more information from you...

Comment: Are *mo*, *mag* and *countfujita* lists of the same length?

Comment: sorry mag is magnitude and mo is month. I am pulling from a file about hurricane data over the course of 67 years so there's multiple data for january,feb,etc but only 6 magnitudes(0,1,2,3,4,5,) but they're repeated throughout the data

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you are looping over `mag` for every item in `mo` when this is not what you want. Let me know if the following fixes your issue:

```
for m in range(len(mo)):
  if mag[m] == 0 and mo[m] ==1 :
      countfujita[m] = countfujita[m] + 1
```

(this assumes that `len(mag) = len(mo)`)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to run successfully you need to ensure that *countfujita* is **at least** as long as the *mo* list.

The following would be a robust approach:

```
mo = [1, 0, 3]
mag = [3, 0, 1, 11]
# construct a list of the same length as *mo* and fill with zeroes
countfujita = [0] * len(mo)

for m in range(len(mo)):
    for o in range(len(mag)):
        if mag[o] == 0 and mo[m] == 1:
            countfujita[m] += 1

print(countfujita)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing multiple lists inside nested loops is error-prone. In general we want to leverage the python built-in modules as much as possible.

For example (starting from the example defined by Lancelot du Lac) we can use `itertools.product` to generate all combinations of `mo` and `mag`. `enumerate` gives us the index corresponding to the element of `mo`:

```
from itertools import product

for (imo, xmo), xmag in product(enumerate(mo), mag):
    if (xmo, xmag) == (1, 0):
        countfujita[imo] += 1
```

---

To push this even further, we can combine this with `Counter` to first generate a list of all `mo` indices and then count. This results in a counter object `Counter({0: 1})` object, similar to a `dict`, which might or might not be appropriate depending on what you do with `countfujita` later on:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

Counter([imo for (imo, xmo), xmag 
         in product(enumerate(mo), mag) 
         if (xmo, xmag) == (1, 0)])

# Counter({0: 1})
```